# Drawing a custom Line component over another Line component, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jcomponent

I am working on a project that involves the need for a custom Line component (so that additional functionality can be included later - i.e., Lines can be removed and moved about), that draws a new Line on a JPanel (i.e., LinePanel) wherever the user presses the mouse (start point) and drags to (end point).  The idea is that the user can click and drag to any point on the panel to create a line (I have included a border in the code to display the bounded rectangle - for feedback).  The below code works fine when clicking directly on the LinePanel, however if the user clicks over another Line component the start position is altered - this is the part that is driving me crazy (I suspect that the problem is occurring inside the mousePressed() logic.  I'm relatively new to Graphics with Java and would really love some feedback.  I'm sure that there is a better way to do this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class LineFun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new LinePanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class LinePanel extends JPanel {
    Point point1 = null, point2 = null;
    Line line = null;

    public LinePanel() {
        LineListener listener = new LineListener();
        addMouseListener(listener);
        addMouseMotionListener(listener);

        setLayout(null);

        setBackground(Color.white);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    private class LineListener extends MouseAdapter {

        /***
         * It feels like this is where the problem is occuring - it works fine when I don't click on another Line
         * component.
         * @param e - event.
         */
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mousePressed(e);
            point1 = e.getPoint();
            if ((e.getSource() instanceof Line)) {
                Line lineComponent = (Line)e.getSource();
                Point componentPoint = lineComponent.point2;

                Point newStart = new Point(point1.x + componentPoint.x, point1.y + componentPoint.y);

                line = new Line(newStart, newStart);
                line.addMouseListener(new LineListener());
                line.addMouseMotionListener(new LineListener());
                add(line);
            }
            else {
                line = new Line(point1, point1);
                line.addMouseListener(new LineListener());
                line.addMouseMotionListener(new LineListener());
                add(line);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseDragged(e);
            point2 = e.getPoint();
            line.setPoint2(point2);

                if ((point2.x - point1.x) >= 0 && (point2.y - point1.y) >= 0) {
                    line.setBounds(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y);
                } else if ((point2.x - point1.x) < 0 && (point2.y - point1.y) < 0) {
                    line.setBounds(point2.x, point2.y, point1.x - point2.x, point1.y - point2.y);
                } else if ((point2.x - point1.x) < 0) {
                    line.setBounds(point2.x, point1.y, point1.x - point2.x, point2.y - point1.y);
                } else {
                    line.setBounds(point1.x, point2.y, point2.x - point1.x, point1.y - point2.y);
                }
                repaint();
        }

    }
}

/***
 * Line class - I've created a border so that I can see the Bounded Rectangle.
 */
    class Line extends JComponent {
        Point point1 = null, point2 = null;

        public Line(Point point, Point point2) {
            point1 = point;
            this.point2 = point2;
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        }

        public void setPoint2(Point point) {
            point2 = point;
        }

    /***
     * The below logic is so that the line originates from the origin (where the mouse press occurs).
     * I feel like there must be a better way to do this.
     * @param page
     */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
            super.paintComponent(page);
            page.setColor(Color.black);

        if (point2.x >= point1.x && point2.y >= point1.y) {
            page.drawLine(0,0, point2.x - point1.x,point2.y - point1.y);
        } else if ((point2.x - point1.x) < 0 && (point2.y - point1.y) < 0){
            page.drawLine(0,0, point1.x - point2.x, point1.y - point2.y);
        } else if (point2.x < point1.x){
            page.drawLine(0, point2.y - point1.y, point1.x - point2.x, 0);
        } else {
            page.drawLine(point2.x - point1.x, 0, 0, point1.y - point2.y);
        }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It feels like this is where the problem is occuring - it works fine when I don't click on another Line component.

Correct. The mouse point is generated relative to the component you click on, since you are adding the mouse listener to all your components.

So in the case where the component is an instance of `Line`, I would guess that you need to convert the mouse points to be relative to your `LinePanel` which would be the parent of the `Line` component.

You can use the `SwingUtiltities.convertPoint(...)` method to do the conversion.

And you can use the `Container.getParent()` method to get the reference to your `LinePanel`

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and created the following GUI.

[image: Line Drawing]

The "trick" is to create an application model to hold the line segments.

I created a `LineSegment` plain Java getter / setter class to hold the two `java.awt.Point` instances that make up one line segment.  This class can be expanded in the future to hold a line color and a line thickness.

I created a `LineSegments` plain java getter/setter class to hold one temporary line segment and a `java.util.List` of line segments.

The application model consists of one or more plain Java getter / setter classes.

The view is a `JFrame` and a drawing `JPanel`.  The drawing `JPanel` draws whatever is in the application model.  When you repaint a drawing `JPanel`, you have to **redraw everything**.  The "memory" is in the application model, not in the view.

You can't see it in the picture, but the GUI draws a red line while you're dragging the mouse.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could post them as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LineDrawingGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LineDrawingGUI());
    }
    
    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private final LineSegments lineSegments;
    
    public LineDrawingGUI() {
        this.lineSegments = new LineSegments();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(this, lineSegments);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Line Drawing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private LineSegments lineSegments;

        public DrawingPanel(LineDrawingGUI lineDrawingGUI, 
                LineSegments lineSegments) {
            this.lineSegments = lineSegments;
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
            
            LineListener listener = new LineListener(lineDrawingGUI, lineSegments);
            this.addMouseListener(listener);
            this.addMouseMotionListener(listener);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            LineSegment lineSegment =  lineSegments.getTemporaryLineSegment();
            if (lineSegment != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                drawLine(g, lineSegment);
            }
            
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (LineSegment segment : lineSegments.getLineSegments()) {
                drawLine(g, segment);
            }
        }

        private void drawLine(Graphics g, LineSegment lineSegment) {
            Point startPosition = lineSegment.getStartPosition();
            Point endPosition = lineSegment.getEndPosition();
            g.drawLine(startPosition.x, startPosition.y, 
                    endPosition.x, endPosition.y);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class LineListener extends MouseAdapter {
        
        private LineDrawingGUI lineDrawingGUI;
        
        private LineSegments lineSegments;
        
        private Point startPosition;

        public LineListener(LineDrawingGUI lineDrawingGUI, 
                LineSegments lineSegments) {
            this.lineDrawingGUI = lineDrawingGUI;
            this.lineSegments = lineSegments;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            this.startPosition = event.getPoint();
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            lineSegments.setTemporaryLineSegment(null);
            LineSegment lineSegment = new LineSegment();
            lineSegment.setStartPosition(startPosition);
            lineSegment.setEndPosition(event.getPoint());
            lineSegments.addLineSegment(lineSegment);
            lineDrawingGUI.repaint();
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            LineSegment lineSegment = new LineSegment();
            lineSegment.setStartPosition(startPosition);
            lineSegment.setEndPosition(event.getPoint());
            lineSegments.setTemporaryLineSegment(lineSegment);
            lineDrawingGUI.repaint();
        }

    }
    
    public class LineSegments {
        
        private LineSegment temporaryLineSegment;
        
        private final List<LineSegment> lineSegments;
        
        public LineSegments() {
            this.lineSegments = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        
        public LineSegment getTemporaryLineSegment() {
            return temporaryLineSegment;
        }

        public void setTemporaryLineSegment(LineSegment temporaryLineSegment) {
            this.temporaryLineSegment = temporaryLineSegment;
        }

        public void addLineSegment(LineSegment lineSegment) {
            this.lineSegments.add(lineSegment);
        }

        public List<LineSegment> getLineSegments() {
            return lineSegments;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class LineSegment {
        
        private Point startPosition;
        private Point endPosition;
        
        public Point getStartPosition() {
            return startPosition;
        }
        
        public void setStartPosition(Point startPosition) {
            this.startPosition = startPosition;
        }
        
        public Point getEndPosition() {
            return endPosition;
        }
        
        public void setEndPosition(Point endPosition) {
            this.endPosition = endPosition;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: As the portion of code is just an example of a larger program that I've been working on - I'd like to avoid a whole redesign (I will if I have to though).  My question is what the advantages are of using an application model to hold 'line' segments, as opposed to letting JPanel take care of that?  Thanks

Comment: @Paul Richard Lewis: [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.